# Php File function doubts: URL or Path

Tags: php

Using the `file` function, is there any difference in using an URL or a path?

```
$my_array = file("http://www.mydomain.com/my_script.php?id=1");
$my_array = file($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."my_script.php?id=1");
```

I'm using the first one, but **I guess** that it's dependant on my server internet conection because, sometimes, despite the fact that the script is called (I know it because my_script.php inserts a row in the database) I don't get the response and $my_array is empty.

Am I right?

If so, using the second call would fill always $my_array with a response. Won't it?

Can I call a file from a path passing arguments in the same way I would do with the URL?

Edit: Thanks a lot for your answers, and sorry if this question is too stupid.. I'm working on some other guy code. He was doing it this way because my_script.php is also called from other server. I'll try to do it with `require` preparing firstly the $_GET variable (a bit tricky but I don't want to touch my_script.php).

Comment: You should mention that mydomain points to your server.

Comment: ¿? How did you notice it points to my server?

Comment: Lucky educated guess...?!

Comment: I don't believe in luck, must be a genious

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any path starting with `http://...` will make an actual HTTP request. Essentially, it'll do the same as if you typed that URL into your browser. If you're doing this for a script on your own server, it's extreme nonsense because:

- it needs to "go out" and establish a TCP connection, to itself
- it ties up another web server process
- it ramps up another separate PHP process
- it doesn't keep the context of the current PHP process
- it may not be able to return anything at all, because it will only return whatever the other script `echo`s out

This only ever makes sense if you're trying to communicate with some other remote server.

On the other hand, using `?id=1` on a local, non-`http://...` file is not possible, since `?id=1` is not a valid part of a file name (or at least it probably doesn't do what you think it does).

What you typically want is something like:

```
require __DIR__ . '/foo.php';
```

This includes the other PHP script in your current script as PHP code. You should be defining functions and classes, use autoload to load them and call them as needed, but this is quite a broad topic of proper code organisation I won't go into here.

Comment: Upvoted both, but selected yours because it's a bit more detailed. Thanks again

Comment: Just one more question, am I right? I mean, doing a file($url) it's possible to make the script run well but, because of the internet connection, don't get its response?

Comment: It's unlikely that the *connection* will be a problem (because there's not much of a network between you and you), though it's certainly possible. It's more likely that the server will be busy and drop the connection.

Comment: I finally will need to do some other script emulating my_script.php but doing what I need to do with the response instead of throw the response with an echo like my_script.php actually does... or recode a bit that script :S.

Comment: And you're right, most likely will be a cpu overload problem, ty

Answer (score 2):

All `file()` does is read a file.  It's intended to load something from disk, but supports any fopen wrapper PHP provides, such as HTTP.

When you pass a URL to `file()`, it goes and fetches that URL from your web server.  Your web server will execute your PHP and return the result, which is what you get back from `file()`.  So no, what you have there are completely different mainly because one involves the web server and PHP, and the other doesn't.

Don't do it this way.  Use `require()` or `require_once()` instead.